# With the maven-release-plugin, how to branch a module and its children?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

Say you have a module named "parent" which has 2 childs "childA" and "ChildB"

If I run

```
mvn release:branch -DbranchName=my-branch
```

in the "parent" folder, it will branch the parent module code to SVN /branches/my-branch WITHOUT the 2 child modules.

I would like release:branch to branch the parent module and all its children to

- /branches/my-branch/parent
- /branches/my-branch/childA
- /branches/my-branch/childB

I didn't found any solution in the doc yet:

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/branch-mojo.html
- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html

Is it feasible ?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Fred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

if the modules are structured hierarchically it works:

/trunk/parent
/trunk/parent/childA
/trunk/parent/childB

but you *must* ensure that SCM parameters are 100% correct.

i.e.:

/trunk/parent/pom.xml

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://svnserver:18080/svn/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svnserver:18080/svn/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>https://svnserver:18080/viewvc/trunk</url>
</scm>
```

/trunk/parent/childA/pom.xml

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://svnserver:18080/svn/trunk/childA</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svnserver:18080/svn/trunk/childA</developerConnection>
    <url>https://svnserver:18080/viewvc/trunk/childA</url>
</scm>
```

/trunk/parent/childB/pom.xml

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://svnserver:18080/svn/trunk/childB</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svnserver:18080/svn/trunk/childB</developerConnection>
    <url>https://svnserver:18080/viewvc/trunk/childB</url>
</scm>
```

Then when you run the following command:
mvn release:branch -DbranchName= -DupdateBranchVersions=true -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=true -DreleaseVersion= -DdevelopmentVersion=

All modules are correctly branched to /branches/ with all versions and SCM properties automatically updated