# maven-release-plugin: Is the folder relevant in the scm section of the pom.xml?

Tags: svn, version-control, maven, pom.xml, maven-release-plugin

We're using a standard svn layout (/branches/x.y, /tags, /trunk) and mvn release (i.e. maven-release-plugin) to perform releases, from the branches.

We usually try to make sure the  section follows the branch, so it looks like this

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://DOMAIN/svn/PROJECT/MODULE/branches/1.5</connection>
    <developerConnection>( same as connection )</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

Can anybody tell me whether the "branches/1.5" at the end is strictly necessary? Or does maven-plugin figure this out anyway? What happens if it's wrong - say I'm on the 1.5 branch and the scm section of the pom say 1.4, or trunk? I have no immediate desire to try it. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the [Maven SCM url used fr Subversion](http://maven.apache.org/scm/subversion.html):

```
scm:svn:http://[username[:password]@]server_name[:port]/path_to_repository
scm:svn:http://svn.apache.org/svn/root/module
```

, what you need is the path to the right Maven module within your repo.
Maven won't be able to infer that path on its own, so the '`branches/1.5`' is necessary.

See for illustrations the SO question "[With the maven-release-plugin, how to branch a module and its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336340/with-the-maven-release-plugin-how-to-branch-a-module-and-its-children)".

Comment: If you're right, that's not a very helpful example. There is not a single example there that DOES specify a particular branch, they all look like what I called scm:svn:http://DOMAIN/svn/PROJECT/MODULE/ rather than scm:svn:http://DOMAIN/svn/PROJECT/MODULE/branches/x.y

Comment: @PapaFreud: but the SO question I linked contains examples more closely in line with your question, no?

Comment: @PapaFreud Basically, you need a path where there is a `pom.xml`.

Comment: OK, I guess I was doing it right all along then. :) We don't do release:branch though, just a plain release:prepare, release:perform, but after checking out a particular branch.